# Adding armature with shift+e, but doesn't mirror in x-axis

Tags: rigging

[the file link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18dIabAA5DMFtNJzHN2T4jTAe0RSk7hfN)
I want to add the armature that mirrors to the x-axis. But with mirror x-axis turned, press shift+e and armature turn to be strange.
[image: both turn to the strange direction. And one is small, the other is big]

If you know what happened, please tell me! Thanks!

Comment: Have you check that the origin and orientation of your armature object is indeed where you think the center should be?

Comment: @Leander Yes, I have. I set it the origin to 3d cursor and it is in the center. I'll upload the file later. If you know how to solve, please tell me! thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your armature object as some rotations.
In object mode, select the armature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> / Rotation to apply it.